# Copy table from another schema doesn't work dynamically

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to copy tables (schema+data) from one schema to another by using:
`create table as select * from my_table`

I want to do it from a certain table list, so I wrote a cursor

```
DECLARE
   p_site nvarchar2(200);
   v_cmd nvarchar2(1000);
   v_tablename nvarchar2(100);

  CURSOR export_running IS
  SELECT  tablename  FROM TABLES_TABLE;
BEGIN
  p_site:='site_name';
  OPEN export_running;
  LOOP
    FETCH  export_running  INTO v_tablename;
    EXIT WHEN export_running%NOTFOUND;
     
     v_cmd:='create table '||v_tablename||' as select * from '||p_site||'.'||v_tablename;
     execute immediate v_cmd;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE export_running;
END;
```

When I run the code I get

```
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 20, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
```

But if I print the statement and run it, it works well.

- Datapump is not an option here.
- I'm doing it on SQL Developer, Oracle version 12.1.
- I have full privileges on both schemas.

Is it a known issue that I cannot **dynamically** create a table from one schema to the other?
Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `NVARCHAR2` data type. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8):

> execute_immediate_statement
>
> dynamic_sql_stmt
>
> String literal, string variable, or string expression that represents
> a SQL statement. Its type must be either CHAR, VARCHAR2, or CLOB.